# Storing joda-time datetime in database

Tags: java, datetime, jpa, jodatime

My application already uses Joda-time for date manipulation with plans to upgrade to jsr 310 in the near future.

Now I need to store VERY accurate timestamp in the database using jpa 2 and hibernate, but `java.util.Date` is not storing the millisecond value.

I found [UserType](http://usertype.sourceforge.net/) and configured my entitybean like this

```
    @Column( name = "TRANSACTION_TIME" )
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime transactionTime;
```

but it still doesn't store the milliseconds.

I passed in this `2010-11-02 12:02:54.945` but when I retrieved it, it was `2010-11-02 12:02:54.000`.

What else do I have to do to get the milliseconds stored and possibly the time zone?

**UPDATE**
I have just checked and the milliseconds actually make it to the database but Hibernate does not include it in the returned results. The same formatter printed the two results so it can't be formatting problem

Comment: Some datastores simply do not store the millisecs in a DATETIME column. Use a large numeric to store it as a number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you want, but you could store the time as a number (=miliseconds since epoch) instead of a datetime field.

Comment: +1 A `long` gives you the precision, is easy to map, and the time zone should be stored elsewhere anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle DATE datatype does not store fractional seconds. You need to use TIMESTAMP or a numeric column as previously suggested. See: http://knol.google.com/k/oracle-date-and-time-data-types